# loadMetadata in Dropbox SDK only listing relative path

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm developing a little application linked in my iPad with my Dropbox account and I'm trying to list a directory tree (root directory) in one explorer I have designed but I'm getting only relative path (application folder) files. I want to list all files in my Dropbox folder, not only relative path. I'm using the following callback (Dropbox iOS SDK instructions):

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
       NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
       for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
          NSLog(@"  %@", file.filename);
       }
   }
}
```

Of course, I call loadMetadata with following code:

```
[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
```

What I'm doing wrong? Applications permissions in Dropbox?

Comment: Which permission does your app have? If it only has "App folder" permission, then you'll only see files within your app folder. If it has "Full Dropbox" permission, then you'll see everything.

Comment: That's it, newbie question. Thanks @smarx